# Mysql display values if i have only user entered value

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

I have a little problem in mysql and i don't know how to solve it.

The scenario is this:

User insert this date: 07.11.1986

I have a table with 3 columns: data, time, gmt
How can i tell sql to display these 2 values from table:

```
|   data    |   time   |   gmt    |
|-----------|----------|----------|
|28.09.1986 | 03:00:00 | 03:00:00 |
|29.03.1987 | 02:00:00 | 04:00:00 |
```

it's obvious that the date inserted by user is between these 2 values.

Comment: so, you want to select the last date before the user-inputted date, and the first date after it?  what are the datatypes for the three columns, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it (assuming your 'data' column is in fact a datetime, and your user input is a string).
Two separate queries to get the lower and upper values, then join together with UNION :

```
(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE STR_TO_DATE('07.11.1986', '%d./%m./%Y')  < data ORDER BY data ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE STR_TO_DATE('07.11.1986', '%d./%m./%Y')  > data ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1)
```